# PyPDF2: why is one page good to extract text and another throws an end of stream error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

```
reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
for page in reader.pages:
  str_page = page.extract_text()
```

The "Unexpected end of stream" error

Example of good page:

{'/Rotate': 0, '/Type': '/Page', '/Parent': IndirectObject(51, 0, 2214350944112), '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 522, 1008], '/Contents': IndirectObject(5, 0, 2214350944112), '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB', '/ImageC'], '/XObject': {'/X6': IndirectObject(13, 0, 2214350944112), '/X5': IndirectObject(11, 0, 2214350944112), '/X4': IndirectObject(10, 0, 2214350944112), '/X3': IndirectObject(8, 0, 2214350944112), '/X2': IndirectObject(7, 0, 2214350944112), '/X1': IndirectObject(6, 0, 2214350944112), '/X17': IndirectObject(32, 0, 2214350944112), '/X16': IndirectObject(30, 0, 2214350944112), '/X15': IndirectObject(28, 0, 2214350944112), '/X14': IndirectObject(27, 0, 2214350944112), '/X13': IndirectObject(25, 0, 2214350944112), '/X9': IndirectObject(18, 0, 2214350944112), '/X12': IndirectObject(23, 0, 2214350944112), '/X11': IndirectObject(21, 0, 2214350944112), '/X8': IndirectObject(16, 0, 2214350944112), '/X7': IndirectObject(15, 0, 2214350944112), '/X10': IndirectObject(20, 0, 2214350944112)}, '/Font': {'/F11': IndirectObject(38, 0, 2214350944112), '/F10': IndirectObject(37, 0, 2214350944112), '/F9': IndirectObject(36, 0, 2214350944112), '/F8': IndirectObject(35, 0, 2214350944112), '/F7': IndirectObject(34, 0, 2214350944112), '/F6': IndirectObject(31, 0, 2214350944112), '/F5': IndirectObject(29, 0, 2214350944112), '/F4': IndirectObject(26, 0, 2214350944112), '/F3': IndirectObject(24, 0, 2214350944112), '/F2': IndirectObject(19, 0, 2214350944112), '/F1': IndirectObject(14, 0, 2214350944112), '/F12': IndirectObject(39, 0, 2214350944112)}}}

Example of Bad page

{'/Rotate': 0, '/Type': '/Page', '/Parent': IndirectObject(51, 0, 1815281175584), '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 522, 1008], '/Contents': IndirectObject(40, 0, 1815281175584), '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB', '/ImageC'], '/XObject': {'/X34': IndirectObject(58, 0, 1815281175584), '/X33': IndirectObject(57, 0, 1815281175584), '/X32': IndirectObject(56, 0, 1815281175584), '/X28': IndirectObject(52, 0, 1815281175584), '/X30': IndirectObject(54, 0, 1815281175584), '/X26': IndirectObject(48, 0, 1815281175584), '/X24': IndirectObject(46, 0, 1815281175584), '/X23': IndirectObject(45, 0, 1815281175584), '/X22': IndirectObject(44, 0, 1815281175584), '/X19': IndirectObject(41, 0, 1815281175584), '/X21': IndirectObject(43, 0, 1815281175584)}, '/Font': {'/F2': IndirectObject(19, 0, 1815281175584), '/F1': IndirectObject(14, 0, 1815281175584), '/F8': IndirectObject(35, 0, 1815281175584), '/F7': IndirectObject(34, 0, 1815281175584)}}}

I've read the exception page for PyPDF2 documentation and I know the recommendation is to use pdfminer in order to extract the remaining text.

usually looking at the Traceback gets me somewhere, but I'm lost on this one

Answer (score 0):

Because one page object is stored correctly and the other one has an unexpected end of the stream.

The issue is that an inline-image was "announced", but then nothing followed. The file just ended.

This is not a bug of pypdf, but a broken PDF document.

If you can share the PDF + if other PDF viewers can show that page properly, you can open an issue in the pypdf issue tracker. We call those "robustness issues".

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

The pdf in question is a Bank Statement, any recommendations to sanitize it without disturbing the error?